# Build failed after Xcode Update 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I update xcode from 6.1 to 6.1.1 and when i try to build my iOS app, it fail.

```
var url = NSURL.URLWithString("https://my.domain.com")
```

This line doesn't throw error with xcode 6.1, but since the update, i have to replace by this line:

```
var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "https://my.domain.com")
```

Moreover, the request with this URL doesn't work any more.

If someone has any explanations.

Thanks

Comment: "doesn't work any more" is not something I can help you with. Please explain what IS happening. Are you getting an error, exception, a crash?

Comment: Nothing happen, the error handler is not called. Same for the success handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like apple replaced the factory method `URLWithString` with `NSURL(string: <#String#>)`, so you should use that insted of `fileURLWithPath`

Comment: Thanks.
But what about the request which doesn't work since I change this code ?

Comment: as the other answer tells, fileURLWithPath refers to local file or directory at path. But you don't want to refer to a local file or directory, so use  NSURL(string: "https://my.domain.com")

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that:
fileURLWithPath: "Initializes a newly created NSURL referencing the local file or directory at path."

You can still use URLwithString, but try calling it like so: (from documentation)

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://my.domain.com"];
```

(objective-c, I realize now you're looking for a Swift answer :)

In Swift:

```
let urlPath: String = "https://my.domain.com"
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
```