# Xcode 6 error 'URLWithString' is unavailable?

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, nsurl

Please help a newbie here. I'm sure this is stupid simple.

I'm following along and learning Xode nicely, but I'm stumped on a basic connection to a URL:

```
var text = textField.text
var url = NSURL.URLWithString(text)
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

I'm getting the following error for the second line above:

**'URLWithString' is unavailable: use object construction 'NSURL(string:)'**

(code is part of a brief tutorial at: http://www.lynda.com/articles/build-first-ios-app-swift)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build failed after Xcode Update 6.1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550625/build-failed-after-xcode-update-6-1-1)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the initializer [`NSURL(string:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initWithString:):

```
var url = NSURL(string: text)
```

Answer (score 24):

Apple changed some of the Swift methods recently, so I've found a few Swift tutorials to be out of date just like what you've encountered.  Luckily, it's telling you exactly what to do instead:

Swift 3 update:
`var url = URL(string:text)`

Swift 2:
`var url = NSURL(string:text)`

Comment: The "NS" was dropped in Swift 3.0. Now simply use "URL".

Answer (score 9):

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {

    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    var text = "http://www.google.com"
    var url = NSURL(string:text)
    var req = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)



    webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(req)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Swift 3.0, the NS prefix is dropped from NSURL:

```
var url = URL(string: text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some object require explicit argument names unless otherwise defined:

```
var url = NSURL.URLWithString(string: text)
```